# Image field not rendering the url in a data-attribute in rendering variant

Tags: sxa

When we try to add a data-attribute to a field which refers to an image field, it displays an image tag instead of the image path/url. Screen shot below for your reference:

[image]

Using SXA 1.9.

Thanks in Advance

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a Scriban object here instead of a field.
Looking at your example, I can understand you have 2 images, Image and ThumbImage and I believe your goal is to have a Html element like that:
<img src="URL_to_IMAGE" **useful params** data-progressive="URL_TO_THUMBIMAGE"/>

This can be done in a one-liner in Scriban:

```
{{ sc_field i_item 'Image' [['data-progressive', i_item.ThumbImage.media_url]] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe only text field are supported, you will have to extend to support link/image fields:

Have a look at following article:

https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2018/10/using-tokens-in-sitecore-sxa-variant.html?m=1

Regards
Bryan

Comment: Answers need to be able to stand on their own; not just be a link to some other resource.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute value being output is the raw value of the associated image field value.

```
<image mediaid=''
```

I followed the same image responsive blog and after some investigation and decompiling the DLLs I found that the value is printed out by:

```
    <renderVariantField>
        <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantField, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants" resolve="true" />
    </renderVariantField>
```

Essentially this happens in the method:

```
protected override string ResolveAttributeValues(string value, Item item, object model)
```

The token is replaced by the raw field value.

I got this same result in Sitecore 9.3 and the matching SXA version.

This is the first processor in that pipeline and whether or not its a bug or just an omission in the code to handle image URL attributes I'm not sure.

Either way here is a solution/patch:

```
 public class MyRenderVariantField : RenderVariantField
{
    protected override string ResolveAttributeValues(string value, Item item, object model)
    {
        var imageResult = RetrieveImageTokenUrl(value, item);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageResult))
            return imageResult;
        IKeyValueSourceFactory <Item> service = new ItemFieldNameKeyValueSourceFactory();
        IKeyValueSourceFactory<object> service2 = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IKeyValueSourceFactory<object>>();
        IPatternProcessor service3 = new PatternProcessor();
        var processed = service.Create(item);
        value = service3.Process(value, processed);
        value = service3.Process(value, service2.Create(model));
        return value;
    }
    protected string RetrieveImageTokenUrl(string value, Item item)
    {
        string singleToken = string.Empty;
        foreach (Match regexItem in new Regex("\\$\\(([^$()]+)\\)", RegexOptions.Compiled).Matches(value))
        {
            singleToken = regexItem.Groups[1].Value;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(singleToken))
        {
            var matchingField = item.Fields[singleToken];
            if (matchingField != null && matchingField.HasValue)
            {
                var imageField = (Data.Fields.ImageField)matchingField;
                if (imageField != null && imageField.MediaItem != null)
                    singleToken = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageField.MediaItem);
            }
        }
        return singleToken;
    }
}
```

Extend the existing RenderVariantField and override the ResolveAttributeValues method.

I added some code at the top of the ResolveAttributeValues that uses a new method to detect if we are handling an image in our Attribute.

Now patch your new Processor in place over the original like so:

```
    <pipelines>
        <renderVariantField>
            <processor type="Sitecore.Foundation.ImageCompression.MyRenderVariantField, Sitecore.Foundation.ImageCompression" resolve="true" />
        </renderVariantField>
    </pipelines>
```